# Flutter Web: Text turns red. Cannot submit Form. Button doesn't work

Tags: flutter

I am experiencing a weird problem with Flutter web in production. The app is hosted on Azure Static Web Apps. When I visit the app, after it finishes loading, all text within the Text() widget turns red, and the Form() no longer works. The ElevatedButton() also does not function. Refreshing the page does not resolve the issue. I have tested it on both an iPhone and a Samsung phone, and the results are the same. However, it works fine on desktop with no problems, and it also functions properly in the development environment. There are no error messages or console logs indicating any issues. I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

flutter doctor output:

```
PS D:\APPS\hcc_ac3_app> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3031], locale en-US)
[✓] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
PS D:\APPS\hcc_ac3_app>
```

Behavior on iPhone: [YouTube Video](https://youtu.be/v5aIUVZUOzQ)

Behavior on Desktop: [YouTube Video](https://youtu.be/eujp2bgQziY)

Comment: Did you try to run flutter clean and then rebuild? Delete build folder? Upgrade Flutter version?

Comment: * flutter pub cache clean
* flutter clean
* flutter pub cache repair
* flutter pub get

Comment: @Andrej, thank you for your response. I do use a CI/CD pipeline to deploy the app to Azure Static Web Apps. The pipeline runs 'flutter pub get && flutter build web --dart-define-from-file=./config.json' to build the app and move the artifacts to Azure Static Web App. I believe that since I use CI/CD, Azure Static Web App is hosting a freshly built app.

Comment: @RahulKushwaha, thank you for your response. Like I mentioned in my above comment, I do use a CI/CD pipeline to deploy the app to Azure Static Web Apps. The pipeline runs 'flutter pub get && flutter build web --dart-define-from-file=./config.json' to build the app and move the artifacts to Azure Static Web App. I believe that since I use CI/CD, Azure Static Web App is hosting a freshly built app.